# Is it safe to use negative integers with size_t?

Tags: c++, c++11, unsigned, size-t

I just saw some C++ code like this. It was using a condition to decide whether to walk forward or backward through a `std::vector`.  The compiler doesn't complain, but I thought `size_t` was unsigned. Is this dangerous?

```
vector<int> v { 1,2,3,4,5 };    
bool rev = true;

size_t start, end, di;
if (rev) {
    start = v.size()-1;
    end = -1;
    di = -1;
}
else {
    start = 0;
    end = v.size();
    di = 1;
}

for (auto i=start; i!=end; i+=di) {
    cout << v[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: The standard defines `std::string::npos` as `static const size_type npos = -1;` which is basically a similar trick. To be pedantic you might prefer: `std::vector<int>::size_type start, end, di;`.

Comment: @Galic: I fail to see what the pedantry (as you call it) achieves, what advantage it has.If a maintainer goes out of his or her way to break things by instantiating `std::vector` with an allocator that provides a silly size type, all that the pedantry does is increase the chance the he or she succeeds in fouling up things. As I see it.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Well you're probably right. As far as I can tell though the standard says `std::vector<int>::size_type` must be unsigned, but I think it can be a different size to `std::size_t`. Although I imagine most implementations will make `size_type` the same as `size_t`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's well defined to use unsigned integers (and `size_t` is unsigned) this way, with wraparound: that behavior is guaranteed by the standard, as opposed to with signed integers, where it's not guaranteed by the standard.

It is however needlessly clever.

As a general rule, to avoid problems due to implicit wrapping promotions to unsigned, use unsigned integers for bit-level stuff, use signed integers for numbers. Where you need a signed integer corresponding to `size_t` there's `ptrdiff_t` for you. Define an `n_items` function with signed result, e.g.

```
using Size = ptrdiff_t;

template< class Container >
auto n_items( Container const& c )
    -> Size
{ return end( c ) - begin( c ); }
```

and you're set to go, no more sillywarnings from the compiler.

---

Instead of the too clever given code

```
vector<int> v { 1,2,3,4,5 };    
bool rev = true;

size_t start, end, di;
if (rev) {
    start = v.size()-1;
    end = -1;
    di = -1;
}
else {
    start = 0;
    end = v.size();
    di = 1;
}

for (auto i=start; i!=end; i+=di) {
    cout << v[i] << endl;
```

do e.g.

```
const vector<int> v { 1,2,3,4,5 };    
const bool reverse = true;  // whatever

for( int i = 0; i < n_items( v );  ++i )
{
    const int j = (reverse? n_items( v ) - i - 1 : i);
    cout << v[j] << endl;
}
```

Comment: `n_items()` should be cached in a loop variable to avoid potentially, and potentially expensively depending on the container type, calling/calculating the size for every loop iteration.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever I need to deal with signed types, I always use:

```
typedef std::make_signed<std::size_t>::type ssize_t; // Since C++11
```

...as a signed alternative to std::size_t.

I appreciate this question is a few years old, but I'm hoping that will help others. Credit to [moodycamel::ConcurrentQueue](https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue/blob/master/blockingconcurrentqueue.h).

Comment: More standard is to use ptrdiff_t, I think, which should be the same as your ssize_t.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to *how safe* that code is but I think it's a pretty poor style. A better way would be to use iterators which support forward or reverse iteration.

For example:

```
std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
bool rev = true;

if (rev)
{
    for (auto itr = v.rbegin(); itr != v.rend(); ++itr)
    {
        std::cout << *itr << "\n";
    }
}
else
{
    for (auto itr = v.begin(); itr != v.end(); ++itr)
    {
        std::cout << *itr << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Somehow that code doesn't compile with g++ 4.8.2. Can you think of any reason?

Comment: I'm not sure (it might have to do with the fact that *rend()* and *begin()* won't evaluate to the same type). It was a conceptual answer; I didn't test it. I'll update with something that actually compiles.

Comment: Speaking of good style, you should declare in-loop variables to cache the `end` iterators to avoid potentially calling/instantiating a new copy for each iteration. ;-)

Comment: @underscore_d Have you checked? Sticking with common idioms provides the best opportunity for compilers to optimize your code, they generally do a better job than humans. :)

Comment: I get your point in the abstract, but here IMO writing `for (auto it = c.begin(), end = c.end(); it != end; ++it)` is so little extra typing - & it's so hard to imagine the optimiser could do any better - that I prefer to spell it out. I think some little things we can do to ensure optimality don't count as premature optimisation, but this may only be my definition! (What I don't like here is that `end` should be `const`, but it's not! But I tend to avoid temptation to declare it `const` outside the loop unless there's already other stuff there.)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe to use negative integers with size_t?

No, it is dangerous. Overflow.

```
size_t a = -1;
std::cout << a << "\n";
```

Output:

```
4294967295 // depends on the system, largest value possible here
```

Comment: This is not dangerous overflow, but well-defined wrap-around. Casting negative numbers to size_t is a common way to return errors from functions that normally return a size; the C standard library itself does this for example in functions like `mbrtoc32()`.